# SQL Server 2008 CAL

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I need to purchase SQL Server 2008 Standard edition, because it's features fit what I need. On the features page, it says it can handle 32,767 user connections, but how does that connect with CALs?

What are CALs and how can they affect a project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CAL is a client access license.

SQL Server 2008 has 3 licensing models (explained [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx)):

- Processor Licensing Model
- Server Plus Device CALs Licensing Model
- Server Plus User CALs Licensing Model

You try and select the cheapest model that meets your requirements.

From this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/pricing-licensing-faq.aspx):

Q: What is the difference between device client access licenses (CALs) and user CALs?

A. A device CAL allows any number of users to gain access to licensed server software from a particular device. A user CAL lets a particular user gain access to licensed server software from any number of devices. In other words, a user CAL covers a particular user's access to the server software from work computers and laptops, as well as from home computers, handheld computers, Internet kiosks, and other devices. A device CAL covers access by multiple users to server software from a single, shared device.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the use of "multiplexing" is not allowed, which means you can't buy a single CAL and have an applications server relay database requests on behalf of its' own connections.

For most projects, certainly in my experience, buying individual CALs doesn't sustain it's initial cost-effectiveness as the system scales. If possible, make the investment in the processor licences.

Answer (score 1):

just to add that Microsoft does not make any enforcement on CAL License. This is purely on paper restriction.

However, In "Per Server" licensing, there is a licensing windows service which allows usage enforcement but this service can be stopped

I wonder why they don't enforce this....